# CNTK - reshape an axis to matrix

Tags: cntk

Given a Tensor whose shape is known only at the compute time, how to convert a Tensor of shape, for e.g., `(n1, n2, m*n)` to `(n1, n2, m, n)` assuming there is a prior condition that, the last dimension is strictly a multiple of n.

Comment: How do you decide `m` and `n` knowing `m*n`?

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko I assume `m*n` to be a multiple of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the only information we have is that the last dimension to be a multiple of n, the following line of code simply does the trick. Here, x is a tensor variable whose shape is computed at the compilation of network.

`x = C.reshape(x, x.shape[:-1] + (-1, n))`